# how to delete custom table in magento 1.9, from database with all it's references?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is dropping table from database is enough , or I need to delete some other things too, so that I can create table with same name again.

Comment: If you want to create a table with same name again, why not just truncate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are deleting any of your custom module make sure

- Backup your database
- Disable your module
- Delete all tables of your module.
- Delete all Config settings form 'core_config_data' table.
- Delete your module enter from `core_resource` table.
- Delete All your code from `app/code/<ModulePool (community/local)>`.
- Clear cache

This will help in removing most of your modules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to delete the table directly

> Go to phpmyadmin-> select db->operations-> drop table.

Create a new table with same name and if different name, specify the table name in app/etc/local.xml